# Include jQuery from another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to include jQuery from a javascript file. I have tried the following, although it doesn't work.

```
var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: AppendChild doesn't automatically parse HTML strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`</script>` closes the opening `<script>` block, even if it's in a string. I would do it this way:

```
(function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = document.location.protocol + '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js';

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
})();
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Just one thing, I have my jquery code in the same .js file that your code now contains (your code is at the top is the .js file) so it won't load the jquery. Any kind of solution to that? Once again, thank you so much!

Comment: why do you need to set script.type?

Comment: @dandavis: Older browsers don't assume that the mimetype is `text/javascript` when you omit the `type`, so they never execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `</script>` anywhere inside a script block, not even inside a string, because it will end the script block there.

Break up the ending tag in the string:

```
var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 (function() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = "text/javascript"; // keeping older browsers happy. 
        script.src = window.location.protocol + '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js';
        // browsers prevent cross-protocol downloading.
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);// In Opera a site can get by without a <head>
    })();
```

Comment: `window.location.protocol` leaves the colon at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the jQuery getScript() method to load jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

...Just kidding.

Try this code:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

From: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Also, if using on an https page, you will need to load the script from an https compatible CDN, like the Google Hosted Libraries (src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js")

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

using a tiny re-usable script adder:

```
function fetch(url){
 var d=document, s='script';
 d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0].parentNode.appendChild(d.createElement(s)).src=url;
}

fetch('//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
```

not all pages have HEADs in all browsers, but if a script is running, so can a sibling script tag...

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the variable script contains the sequence `</script>` which you can not make it appears as it is in your code, because browser will assume(and it must) that it is `<script>` tag close.
for example if your script code contains syntax error, which is a string variable that has no close `"` it will looks like

```
<script>var bad = "abcd ;</script>
```

to solve this you can break the `</script>` string like `"</scr" + "ipt>"` or you could escape it: `"<\/script>"`

so:

```
var script = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Second thing is that `appendChild()` function accept a Node element and not a string

so:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Anyway, I prefer to use a module and JavaScript loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).